# How to prove: $f_k \to f$ in $C_c ^\infty (\mathbb{R}^n)$ if and only if $f_k \to f$ in $C_c ^\infty (K)$ for some compact $K$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I am currently reading *Terrence Tao - An epsilon of room*, and a question appeared during solving an exercise in the book.

Definitions from the book:

For each compact $K$, $C_c ^\infty (K)$ is the set of smooth functions on $\mathbb R ^d$ with support in $K$. It has a topology given by the seminorms $|f|_{\alpha} = \sup_{x \in \mathbb R^d} |\partial^\alpha f (x)|$ for $\alpha$ a multi-index.

Call a seminorm $\| \|$ on $C^\infty_c({\mathbb R}^d)$ good if it is a continuous function on $C^\infty_c(K)$ for each compact $K$. We then give $C^\infty_c({\mathbb R}^d)$ the topology defined by all good seminorms.
(This definition is not in the book itself, it is from the errata which is posted on Tao's blog.)

My question: An exercise from the book is: For each $f_k, f \in C_c^\infty (\mathbb R^d)$,
$f_k \to f$ in $C_c ^\infty (\mathbb{R}^n)$ if and only if there exists a compact $K$ with support of $f_k$ and $f$ is in $K$, and $f_k \to f$ in $C_c ^\infty (K)$.

How can I prove this? The definition of the topology on the whole test function space seems to be so exotic, and I am having a hard time.

Comment: I know how to do it but I'm not familiar with notation of MathJax yet, so I cant write it to You :) Every my post so far has to be edited by other people cause i dont want to spend time learning this :)

Comment: This is a particular case of a theorem of Dieudonne and Schwartz about LF-spaces.